# Non-Noetherian Stable Homotopy

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, stable-homotopy

There seems to be quite a bit of theory developed to deal with "stable homotopy" in the sense of the derived category of a Noetherian ring, or just any situation where the endomorphism ring of the generator is Noetherian.  While there are certainly obvious examples of non-Noetherian stable homotopy categories, are there any references giving a general theory? If not, what sort of things get in the way?

Comment: You question is somewhat vage, but if I understand correctly what you mean, the answer is that not only there's no general theory, but most problems and open and all answers seem to be possible. Probably you know Neeman's paper entitled "Oddball Bous"eld classes".

Comment: @Fernando Muro No in fact I don't! I'll look into it. I guess I was just wondering if there was some specific algebraic obstruction, i.e. is there a stable homotopy structure on the derived category of a non-Noetherian ring? 

Comment: I have also just discovered an extremely brief discussion of it at: http://www.math.uwo.ca/~schebolu/apping/UW/future-research.pdf

Comment: @Jon Most triangulated categories come from a stable model category, but the derived category of a non-noetherian ring is still very much unknown. The first stamente is purely formal, while the second is sort of 'down-to-earth'.

Comment: @Fernando thanks! I've read Neeman's paper, and a bit by another fellow Luke Wolcott. This is a really interesting topic! Seems like for non-Noetherian rings stuff gets complicated quick :)

Comment: @Jon: "Is there a stable homotopy structure on..." Of course! This applies in huge, huge generality. One can put a symmetric monoidal, stable model structure on the category of chain complexes of $\mathcal{O}$-modules on *any ringed space*.

Comment: If you're willing to leave out the word "monoidal" until you get to the actual homotopy category, then this is actually pretty easy to do for just a ring, and it would be a good exercise.

Comment: Hmmm- I'm having trouble finding a reference of the "stable" part of "stable model category" BUT this much I know: The derived category of any grothendieck abelian category is an "axiomatic stable homotopy category" in the sense of HPS... but the only way I see how to prove this at the moment is to go through $\infty$-categories... I imagine there's a more elementary way of doing this...

Comment: Alternatively one could use http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/zdga17.pdf and all the hard work of May and others to make stable model category structures! 

Comment: @Dylan You cannot check that the derived category of Grothendieck category is a stable homotopy category in the sense of Hovey-Palmieri-Strickland in such generality because you would lack of a tensor structure and some other features. The best result in that direction I know is due to Alonso-Jeremías-Pérez-Vale http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0493.pdf on the basis of previous work by Alonso-Jeremías-Souto

Comment: Here's a potentially useful source: Mark Hovey's "Open Problems" page. In this link he lists 2 problems for non-Noetherian homotopy theory which may or may not have been answered by now: http://math.wesleyan.edu/~mhovey/problems/axiomatic.html

Comment: @Fernando's second comment: Daniel Bravo has done some work towards the stable derived category of non-Noetherian rings. In particular, his thesis proves that for any $R$ you have a model category whose homotopy category is the stable derived category. See the following link for more detail. There are a lot of slides, and a preprint is in the works. http://people.usm.maine.edu/dbravo/publications.html

Comment: @David that sounds like exactly the type of thing I would like to know about. All in all, it sounds like the answer to my question is: no. There does not seem to be much of a general theory. 

Comment: @Fernando: Here's what's confusing me... we seem to have a monoidal model structure on Ch($\mathcal{O}$) for any locally ringed space, via results in here: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-07/S0002-9947-06-04157-2/S0002-9947-06-04157-2.pdf

Since the homotopy category thereof IS the derived category... that gives the results for most cases of interest, yes? You're right that it doesn't work for an arbitrary Grothendieck abelian category BUT this seems to say that we can do it for, in particular, non-noetherian rings. Also the paper of Shipley certainly takes care of that and 

Comment: much much more...

Comment: @David: I'm having trouble seeing how Daniel's work is not subsumed in Shipley's work above- what am I missing?

Comment: @Dylan Yes, as I said in my very first comment, most of triangulated categories come from stable model categories, no to be confused with stable homotopy categories in the sense of [HPM]. I feel we're getting muddled up with the terminology here.

Comment: @Fernando: Yes but the homotopy category of a symmetric monoidal stable model category is a stable homotopy category, yeah? For example, HR-module spectra with the smash product, where R can, in particular, be any ring

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to whether you're claiming that (a) we don't know if D(R) is a stable homotopy category, or (b) we don't know that every stable homotopy category comes from a stable model category. I disagree with (a), as I said above, and (b) is probably true using the same example that you give in your paper on the subject. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Dylan you're taking me terribly wrong, I've given a reference above to the theorem saying that $D(R)$ is a stable homotopy theory, i.e. the contrary of (a), and about (b) I've said that most triangulated categories come from stable model categories, since I don't believe Jon is interested incounterexamples.

Comment: @Jon: Daniel was my academic brother, so I have lots of notes from his talks. I'll bring them down to Virginia next week and we can chat about it there.

Comment: @Dylan: I haven't thought about Daniel's work in a while, so I hope I don't have this wrong, but he's finding a model structure on the stable module category (mod out by projective modules) over an arbitrary ring $R$. I don't believe this category arises out of a spectrum. It's homotopy category is the *stable* derived category, so there's a triangulated structure. Doesn't Shipley's work get you an unstable derived category? Anyway, even if you got the same homotopy category I'm sure the model categories are different. In particular, Daniel's is Abelian (constructed using Cotorsion Pairs)

Comment: Guys, you're making yourself a mess. Shipley's paper linked above is stable and abelian.

Comment: What does "stable derived category" even mean? I know of no derived categories that are not stable...

And Fernando, apologies- I think we agree completely, I was just confused by the comment "the derived category of a non-noetherian ring is still very much unknown". I guess you were talking about Bousfield classes, etc. Sorry for this silliness.

Comment: @David: Oh I get it. But yeah, that should be called "stable module category" not "stable derived category". 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, various things have been said in the comments, and I'd like to say something both coherent and correct since many of my comments above have been neither.

Here's what I understand about all of this.

First and foremost, unless I'm missing something big, it is absolutely the case that $D(R)$ is a stable homotopy category for *any* ring $R$. Here is a silly way-too-much-machinery reason why, with the benefit that it has references that I know of off the top of my head: The category of dg-modules over R (equiv. chain complexes) is Quillen equivalent to the category of HR-module spectra (http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/zdga17.pdf). Thanks to, for example, May (pick a paper of his at random and it will probably contain this result), this has the structure of a symmetric monoidal stable model category, which turns its homotopy category into a stable homotopy category in the sense of HPS.

Second, if you're asking if people have a "general theory" for stable homotopy categories with a non-Noetherian endomorphism ring, the answer is absolutely yes, in many different guises. One can study symmetric monoidal stable model categories (of which there are many, most of which do not have a Noetherian endomorphism ring for generators). One can study symmetric monoidal stable $\infty$-categories which are basically the same. One can try to prove results similar to the nilpotence and classification theorem in these settings, this has been done for: (i) D(R) where R is *any* commutative ring [Thomason], (ii) D(R) where R is *any* epsilon-commutative, G-graded ring [Dell'Ambroglio, Stevenson], (iii) stmod(kG) where G is a finite group scheme [Friedlander-Pevtsova, Benson-Carlson-Rickard], (iv) D(X) where X is a quasi-compact, quasi-separated scheme [Thomason], and (v) $\mathcal{S}$ the category of finite spectra [Devinatz-Hopkins-Smith]. There are some others but I'm less familiar with them...

The thing that absolutely does *not* work, fails miserably actually, for non-Noetherian situations is an attempt to classify the localizing subcategories. Luke Wolcott knows a lot about how bad this can get (his very recent thesis was about it). I'm pretty sure Balmer has written some things about what one can say generally if you *are* in the Noetherian case. The point is that it's not even clear what a "general theory" would look like in the non-Noetherian case for stuff like localizing subcategories... again, Luke knows much more about this than me, so you should ask him. Fernando sums it up nicely in his original comment.

Finally, let me try to clear up two things I said in the comments (someone should correct me if I'm wrong):

1. The category of chain complexes on a Grothendieck abelian category can be given the structure of a stable model category in which the weak equivalences are the quasi-isos.
2. The category of chain complexes of $\mathcal{O}$-modules on any ringed space admits a symmetric monoidal model structure, which means that the unbounded derived category is at the very least a tensor-triangulated category (it's not immediately obvious that the tensor structure plays nice with the triangular structure, but it would be very strange to me if this wasn't true or obvious to someone else?)

Comment: @Dylan Thanks! This is a great answer.  I think that I should have been more clear in that the things I am really interested in are localizing subcategories and Bousfield lattices, which indeed, is stuff that Luke knows a lot about. Sometimes I forget that there is a lot more relevant information to categories besides their localizing subcategories ;-). I have read a little of Luke's work, where he shows that the situation can get really bad. I guess I just wanted to see if there was something general like HPS section 6 for non-Noetherian rings, but I think not.